# Bind format in Reapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a Bind method in Reapater to format currency value

```
<%# Bind("Amount", "{0:$#,#0.00}")%>
```

is not working while the same bind method working for DataGrid,GridView

I tried the same with

```
<%# Eval("Amount", "{0:$#,#0.00}")%>
```

and DataBinder also, but not working reapter but fine with DataGrid,GridView.

Thanks for helps.

Comment: What is your input and what format do you want exactly?

Comment: Input is in string format ex:120.00 want to format to $120.00

Comment: '<%# Bind("Amout", "{0:$#,#0.00}")%>' is working in DataGrid and GridView but not in reapeater

Answer (score 0):

```
<%# Eval("Amount", "{0:$#,#0.00}")%>
```

working in case if the Amount is in Integer not in string format.